# using contains and createArray in Azure ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-marketplace

I am writing createUIdefinition.json ARM template. I want to dynamically select the value of certain parameter - lets call parameterC in maintemplate.json based on the provided values of A and B in UI definition template. Now B is optional and existance of it depends on value selected by user for variable A. So I have wrote template something like below:

```
        "name": "dropdownA",
        "type": "Microsoft.Common.DropDown",
        "label": "dropdownA",
        "defaultValue": "1.1",
        "constraints": {
            "allowedValues": [
            {
                "label": "1.1",
                "value": "1-1"
            },
            {
                "label": "1.2",
                "value": "1-2"
            },
            {
                "label": "1.3",
                "value": "1-3"
            },

        ]
        },
        "visible": true


        "name": "dropdownB",
        "type": "Microsoft.Common.DropDown",
        "label": "dropdown B",
        "defaultValue": "valueX",
              "toolTip": "Choose value",
              "constraints": {
                "allowedValues": [
                {
                    "label": "valueX",
                    "value": "x"
                  },
                 {
                    "label": "valueY",
                    "value": "y"
                  }
                ]
            },
            "visible": "[contains(createArray('1-1','1-2'), basics('dropdownA'))]"  ### make this element visible only if value of A is in ['1-1','1-2']
```

However, I found while I add this condition : [contains(createArray('1-1','1-2','1-2'), basics('dropdownA'))] for dropdown B, Azure UI keep waiting and basically doesn't go to summary page of offer nor it reflects any error that I can debug. If I remove [contains(createArray('1-1','1-2','1-2'), basics('dropdownA'))] , it works fine.

Am i missing something?

Comment: createArray is not supported in createUIDef, @juvchan has an alternate solution below...

Comment: @bmoore-msft, I expect this condition: [contains(['1-1', '1-2'], basics('dropdownA'))] should work but it doesn't, could it be an potential issue or I miss something? Thanks very much.

Comment: try using the parse function to get the array - you probably have to escape the single quotes...  Not 100% certain that will work, but worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the visible condition for DropDownB is set as:

`"visible": "[not(equals('1-3', basics('dropdownA')))]"`,

I am able to see the DropDownB only visible when the selected value of DropDownA is either **1-1** or **1-2**, which I believe is what you exactly expected.

Hope this helps!

Here is my fully tested createUiDefinition template which works.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/0.1.2-preview/CreateUIDefinition.MultiVm.json",
  "handler": "Microsoft.Compute.MultiVm",
  "version": "0.1.2-preview",
  "parameters": {
    "basics": [
      {
        "name": "dropdownA",
        "type": "Microsoft.Common.DropDown",
        "label": "dropdownA",
        "defaultValue": "1.1",
        "constraints": {
          "allowedValues": [
            {
              "label": "1.1",
              "value": "1-1"
            },
            {
              "label": "1.2",
              "value": "1-2"
            },
            {
              "label": "1.3",
              "value": "1-3"
            }
          ]
        },
        "visible": true
      },
      {
        "name": "dropdownB",
        "type": "Microsoft.Common.DropDown",
        "label": "dropdown B",
        "defaultValue": "valueX",
        "toolTip": "Choose value",
        "constraints": {
          "allowedValues": [
            {
              "label": "valueX",
              "value": "x"
            },
            {
              "label": "valueY",
              "value": "y"
            }
          ]
        },
        "visible": "[not(equals('1-3', basics('dropdownA')))]"
      }
    ],
    "steps": [],
    "outputs": {}
  }
}
```

Reference: [CreateUiDefinition functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/create-uidefinition-functions#logical-functions)

**Update:**
@bmoore-msft is right.

If you refer to the reference link above, **createArray()** is not supported as part of the CreateUiDefinition functions

Comment: @juvchan...correct. Thanks for the answer. That will work out. Later, I figured that we can solve it using [not(equals('1-3', basics('dropdownA')))] or [or(equals('1-1', basics('dropdownA')), equals('1-1', basics('dropdownA')))]. I expect to grow amount of A values which is why at first place I was looking for solution similar to createArray. But, I guess I can solve with boolean operators - not, or, and, etc.....

Comment: @ForeverLearner, you're welcome. Thanks for accepting my answer